# Data frame losing ability to call method when passed as an argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a script I'm working on, I have a data frame variable I am passing as an argument to another method. Previously in this original method, if I were to call data_frame.loc[x] it would work without issue, however now in the next method with data_frame passed through, it does not recognize this method.

```
def _validate_result_for_attribute(self, result_file, test_summary):
    
    data_frame = GazeTest.get_data_frame_from_csv(result_file) 

    for i in range(len(data_frame)):
        if not (self._validate_eyes_available(data_frame)):
            data_frame = data_frame.drop([i]) 
  
    self._update_test_case_fields(data_frame, result_file, test_summary)
    
    
def _validate_eyes_available(data_frame, index):
    # Checking if the each eye is available
    if (data_frame.loc[index, RIGHT_EYE_STATUS] == 1 and
        data_frame.loc[index, LEFT_EYE_STATUS] == 1):  
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Error reads;

```
object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Tried to use .loc method but was given an error.

Comment: Please provide the line of in which you use the function (ideally also provide a example input) and the exact and complete error traceback.

Comment: the method where I'm having the issue is called in the if statement of the method above, the data frame object would look like a table with multiple columns and rows, RIGHT_EYE_STATUS being an example of one of these columns. The error reads "(script name) - WARNING - Error in reading result : (csv file) : 'GazeTest' object has no attribute 'loc'". GazeTest here is the name of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an issue in your code: when you call `_validate_eyes_available(data_frame)` You didn't pass the index. this might cause an error for you in this  `data_frame.loc[index, RIGHT_EYE_STATUS]` since you using index and you didn't pass it.

regarding the loc attribute error, you need to make sure that `data_frame` variable is actually dataframe. just print it and make sure before passing it
`print(type(data_frame))`

Comment: Ah yes I had edited the method to include index so I missed that thank you very much. Its always the smallest thing haha.

Comment: @EoinO'Reilly ^^ yes it always those things ^^ i voted you question up so you now be able to help to community more <3